# Centering button on website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, button, grid

```
<body>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse inverse" id="navbar-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="about">
            <h4>text</h4>
            <p class="text</p>
            <div class="imgWrapper">
                <img id="photo" src="path/to/file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="social">
            <p>text</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a id="logoutButton" href="logout.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-     
          primary">Logout</a>
        <button id="navbar-button" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Manager</a>
            </div>
    </div>

    <section class="jumbotron text-xs-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album list</h1>
        <p id="jumbotron-header-text" class="lead text-muted">text</p>
          <p>
              <div id="fakeButton" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                  <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
                  <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
              </div>
          </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

...

I'm trying to center the element with the id "fakeButton" on my Jumbotron, and I'm failing miserably. Things I've tried:

1) CSS Selector

```
#fakeButton {
    margin: auto !important;
    float: none !important;
}
```

2) Using bootstrap class text-center:

```
<div class="span7 text-center"></div>
```

I'm using Bootstrap 4. Most of the code is taken from this Bootstrap example:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/album/

I've made sure Bootstrap is installed correctly, but I can't seem to figure out how to center that element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Bootstrap's `text-center` class with `col-xs-12` on `#fakeButton`.

Use:

```
<div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div id="fakeButton" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
</div>
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
   <div class="navbar-collapse collapse inverse" id="navbar-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="about">
            <h4>text</h4>
            <p class="text"></p>
            <div class="imgWrapper">
                <img id="photo" src="path/to/file"/>
            </div>
        </div>
           <div class="social">
            <p>text</p>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>

    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a id="logoutButton" href="logout.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-     
          primary">Logout</a>
        <button id="navbar-button" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Manager</a>
            </div>
    </div>

    <section class="jumbotron text-xs-center">
      <div class="container">
        <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album list</h1>
        <p id="jumbotron-header-text" class="lead text-muted">text</p>
          <p>
              <div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
                  <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
                  <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
              </div>
          </p>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

Your markup is incorrect, change the following:

This:

```
  <p class="text</p>
```

To this:

```
  <p class="text"></p>
```

And this:

```
 <div id="fakeButton" class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
```

To this:

```
 <div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12">
```

---

The class `text-xs-center` in your `.jumbotron` element is already centering the button.

The button has `display: inline-block`, that is why it is centered with `text-align: center` declared in its ancestor.

---

### EDIT:

You actually have more things to correct:

Wrap your `#fakeButton` in a `.row` not in a `<p>` tag.

Change this:

```
<p>
  <div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
  </div>
</p>
```

To this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
  </div>
</div>
```

And then add this to your CSS:

```
input[type="file"] {
    display: block;
}
```

---

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse inverse" id="navbar-header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="about">
      <h4>text</h4>
      <p class="text"></p>
      <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img id="photo" src="path/to/file" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-dark bg-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a id="logoutButton" href="logout.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-     
          primary">Logout</a>
    <button id="navbar-button" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-header" aria-controls="navbar-header" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"></button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Media Manager</a>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="jumbotron text-xs-center">
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="jumbotron-heading">Album list</h1>
    <p id="jumbotron-header-text" class="lead text-muted">text</p>
    <div class="row">
      <div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12">
        <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
        <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the `text-center` class to the button itself :

```
<label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center">Select Image</label>
```

or change your html to this instead:

```
<div id="fakeButton" class="col-xs-12 text-center">
    <label for="files" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
</div>
```